# mobile/phone emulator for html files on hard drive?

Tags: html, mobile, emulation

I have a website built on my hard drive that is not yet on the web.  I'd like to check how to displays on various mobile devices prior to uploading to the web.  I have downloaded a few emulators, but they seem to only "point" to a website and I cannot make them display a html file on my hard drive.  Any help or pointers?  I'm new to website development and learning while helping a friend.

Comment: Google Chrome can emulate mobile devices. Simply open the developer tools with Ctrl-Shift-I then select the Emulation tab (next to console and Search) You can pick iPhones, Galaxys, Xperias, Kindles, Crackberrys and a bunch of others. Short of installing a webserver and using an actual device, this seems to be the easiest option I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

**Run website on your hard disk:**

To run a website on your computer you need to have a web server, You should download one of these
[mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/), [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Then put your website on the web server software root folder.

---

**Mobile Version:**

Adobe Dreamweaver has a further for web designer who wants to see websites with mobile

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/how-to-build-a-native-mobile-application-in-dreamweaver-cs5.5.html

The adobe mobile simulator works like mobile and you don't need to upload your website and just test it with adobe Dreamweaver mobile simulator

**Other mobile version:**

If you are going to do it with your browser firefox you can press **ctrl+shift+m**

Comment: I'll clarify.  I have a bunch of .html files that are all linked to each other and have various information on them.  When I click on them it behaves like a website in a browser.  So, to me, that is "having a website on my hard drive" in a non-technical sense.  I'd like to do the same thing but with a browser that mimics how the .html files are viewed on mobile devices.

Comment: @SethMyers Dreamweaver is the real mobile version, if you browse Google with Dreamweaver mobile simulator Google can't detect that you are browsing with computer and set you the mobile version for you.

Answer (score -1):

Hey if your phone and the computer with the harddrive are in the same wifi network, I would do it like this:

Install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org). It is a very easy to-use, preconfigured webserver for development. After installing it, create a folder for your website (example: "mywebsite") in the "htdocs" folder in the xampp installation folder.

Open Xampp and start the apache webserver. Now, when you enter "localhost/mywebsite" as a URL in your browser, you will see the content of the folder. If you enter "localhost/mywebsite/mysite.html" you will see the "mysite.html" file rendered as a website.
Now as long as your apache sever is running, you should be able to access the site from any device within your network, without further configurations (like port forwarding or DynDNS).

Edit: Now as I reread your question I see that you don't want to test the site with real devices but with emulators. Well, I hope it is still helpful.